# Android Random Caller

Tags: android

I am triying to make a program which call someone from my contacts ramdomly and I try to do first take all of my contacts in an arraylist and using randomgenerator method call contacts as their index in my arraylist. But I have a problem with this code. It is not complete just triyng to take contacts in an arraylist but when I push the button app is closing. why ?

```
package com.example.uskudar.randomcaller;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.*;
import android.database.Cursor;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
Context context;

ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

public void addContacts(){

    //to store name-number pair
    String obj = new String();

    try {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            obj = phoneNumber;
            contacts.add(obj);

            Log.e("Contact list ", " "+contacts);
        }
        phones.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public  void callRandom(View view){

    addContacts();


}
}
```

And this is the logcat

01-12 15:34:52.846 3695-3695/com.example.uskudar.randomcaller E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.uskudar.randomcaller, PID: 3695
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method callRandom (MainActivity)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Post the crash logcat.

Comment: So, you want to bore all your contacts by randomly calling them every now and then?! I'm lucky not to be in your contact list, then!

Comment: So funny :) it is a project homewok

Comment: As per "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/4037594)", it is good form to mention that this is a homework problem. Related to your actual problem, it looks like the button whose onClick is called is in something other than mainActivity. What exactly does the layout xml look like?

Comment: Addendum to my previous comment: I tried it on my phone, and I expect the xml says `onClick="callRandom (MainActivity)"`, which would cause the default click listener to look for a method `public void callRandom (MainActivity)(View v)` which you might notice is not proper Java syntax.

Comment: <Button
        android:text="Call"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="192dp"
        android:onClick="callRandom (MainActivity)"/>

Answer (score 0):

The xml you posted in comments says `android:onClick="callRandom (MainActivity)"`, which causes the default click listener to look for a method `public void callRandom (MainActivity)(View v)` in MainActivity or its parent classes. You might notice this is not proper Java syntax, which in turn is the cause of your problem.